# Saving Ordering Of A Sortable List Using jQuery UI

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui, plugins

I am currently working on a wordpress function which allows users to add links to the side bar of their website (and automatically generates the domain extension based on the users input). I am currently trying to implement jQuery UI's sortable function to allow users to order their links the way they like. The sortable function is working great, however the order will not save once the page is refreshed. I have looked everywhere and it seems that I should be using ajax and some type of update function within the jQuery.

right now I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("tbody#existing").sortable({
helper: fixHelper}).disableSelection();
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to communicate the item order back to the server and that probably means AJAX. Once the server has this info then it needs to store it someplace (the database), then later it needs to retrieve it, and finally do something useful with it. This puts you squarely in the middle of "plugin development."

There is (at least) one plugin that does something like this, [*My Link Order*](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-link-order/). You could use that, or use it as a learning tool to develop your own plugin.

Some other pages that may be useful to you:

- [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [Creating Options Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Comment: I am currently building my own plugin and all the functions are working properly, I just can't figure out how to implement ajax in the jquery and how to build a function for the loop. I built a function to update when an item is deleted - but it doesn't seem to be the same.

Comment: Sorry for the time lag, but I'm on "staycation." If you don't have an answer by tomorrow morning (PDT) I'll try to come up with something. If you have code that you think *should* work, try posting it to pastebin.com and give the URL here so I can look at it.

Comment: @Jamie: Can you give me a link to your site?